# Domain based email aliasing

Tags: email, dns

The email addresses that we have are defined `specificnamespace@gmail.com`

I was wondering if there is any way to have an email address that is namespace agnostic, meaning say I dont have a preset address `anything@mydomain.com`. Can the email sent to this address not bounce and instead land to `email@mydomain.com`

I basically want to create a mapping such as this:

```
<anything>@mydomain.com ----> email@mydomain.com
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which SMTP/MTA server do you use?

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip Whatever is provided by my hosting provider. For me it is, stmp.<mydomainname>.com

Comment: Yes, this can be done. It used to be postmaster or root (or similar) and any email addresses not caught by the accounts not set up would route to a single email. It depends on how you configure it and what software/provider you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more, it's hard to give specific instructions. But what you are looking for (if I understand your question correctly) is typically called a [catchall](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-all) email address.

This address is defined in your SMTP (mail) settings. Any address defined (e.g `email@mydomain.com`) will be the default receiving email address for any address that doesn't already exist on the server (i.e that would normally "bounce" as undeliverable).

[image: catchall email]